# I need someone to help in web designing languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need someone to help or work with me to learn web designing languages, 
I need people have knowledge in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and JQuery.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. What kind of help do you need?

Comment: If you're just starting out, I'd recommend taking a look at the w3schools tutorials ( https://www.w3schools.com/ ), play around with some code, then let us know any specific issues you're having.

Comment: If you desire instructor-led training, you can contact me and we can discuss your needs further. You can visit our site and get our contact information at: http://techtrainsolutions.com.

Comment: There is also Documentation section on Stackoverflow, asking a broad question is not Stacoverflow's policy favourite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that what I am going to write is meant as a comment but since I am not able to comment yet, I will post it as an answer solely for the purpose of not letting down someone who wants to learn to write code.

elsoufiane, there is no web designer language because web designer is focusing on designing websites and not developing them. One may be able to do both but that doesn't mean they are the same thing. Designing involves using graphic design software to build UI for a website. Developing involves writing code in order to turn a website design (mockup) into code.

Now that we have cleared this up, let's move onto the next thing which is what kind of web developer you want to be. There are **3 distinct roles**:

- **Front-end Web Developer**
- **Back-end Web Developer**
- **Full-Stack Web Developer**

Front-end web developer focuses on the front-end. That means he is focusing on turning a website design into code but that process only involves the aesthetic and a bit of functional part of the website.

Back-end Web Developer focuses on building the back-end infrastructure. He builds on top front-end to make sure the website is serving its purpose.

Example: A **web designer** comes up with a design for a new theme. A **front-end web developer** makes sure that its design is "translated" into code so that you can type something.com and be able to see a website that is exactly the same or at least similar. The **backend developer** makes sure that users can register on the website and that they are served with content from a database.

Finally, a full stack web developer is someone who is both a front-end and back-end web developer. This means not only he can turn a website design into code but it can also add all the functionality it needs for it to work as required.

And to answer your question; you don't need a buddy to help you learn a language. All you have to do is for someone to lay down a map and you walk on its path. And this is why I am giving you this link so that you can have everything planned out without worrying.

Link: https://github.com/bmorelli25/Become-A-Full-Stack-Web-Developer#start-here

I hope I have helped you. If you have any questions, leave a comment and I will help you out.